# Connecting to mqtt node js client using tls

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mqtt, mosquitto

There is minimal explanation on the documents and I couldn't find any example using node js as most if it is using mqtt.js. I need to connect a client to the mqtt server using tls. Below is how I am trying to establish the connection.

```
    export interface SecurityOptions {
    keyPath: string;
    certPath: string;
    cAPath: string;
    passphrase: string;
    rejectUnauthorized: boolean;
  }

  export interface MqttOptions {
    clientId: string;
    protocolId: string;
    protocolVersion: number;
    keepAlive: number;
    clean: boolean;
    reconnectPeriod: string;
    will: IWillMessage;
 }

   let mqttOptions: MqttOptions;

   let securityOptions: SecurityOptions;

   mqttOptions = {
    clientId: '100',
    protocolId: 'MQTT',
    protocolVersion: 4,
    keepAlive: 1000,
    clean: false,
    reconnectPeriod: '1000',
    will: willMessage
  };

  securityOptions = {
      keyPath: 'G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/tls-key.pem',
      certPath: 'G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/tls-cert.pem',
      cAPath: 'G:/Projects/Kube2/edge-node-sdk-js/crt.ca.cg.pem',
      passphrase: '',
      rejectUnauthorized: true
    };

     this.client = mqtt.connect(url, tls.connect({
      key: fs.readFileSync(securityOptions.keyPath),
      ca: fs.readFileSync(securityOptions.cAPath),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(securityOptions.certPath),
      passphrase: securityOptions.passphrase
    }),mqttOptions);
```

but its throwing me the following error.

```
Details:
    code: EADDRNOTAVAIL
    errno: EADDRNOTAVAIL
    syscall: connect
    address: 127.0.0.1
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
Stack:
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1 - Local (0.0.0.0:5625)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at connect (net.js:849:16)
    at net.js:984:7
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I connect to the mqtt client passing both the mqtt options and the tls options? Please advice.

Comment: Which broker are you using and can you connect to it without TLS? Also what port are you running the TLS enabled listener on and do you have a firewall enabled?

Comment: I tested using mqtt pub. That is getting published. I am using the mosquitto broker available for download. And I'm running it on 8883. No I have turned off firewall.